# Communication between Play! project and Java project

Tags: java, playframework, communication

Good morning to all.

I have two projects, one as Java Project, and other made with Play!.
Both projects are in Eclipse IDE.
I need to consume a method in Play! project from Java Project.

How can I do that?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used the Play Framework myself, but what you usually do is put the JAR-file you like to use the method from in the "lib" folder in your play project and tell your IDE to add the lib to your java classpath. I'm guessing you're using an IDE to develop your app (would be great if you could mention it in this case).

That should be enough to access the method from the java project and compile your code. I'm not sure if you need to configure the play project to access the lib at runtime.

For more specific help you need to provide more info what you actually want to do and what tools you're using.

Comment: Sorry for that, i'm using Eclipse for two projects.